# How to populate data in knockout js through ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an json object which I am responding from servlet to knockout js. I want to initialize this data in my view model for that I am writing this code.

```
success: function (data) 
{ 
    var jsondata = data['jsonObj'];
    self.PopulateStates = ko.computed(function(){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(jsondata, function(item){
            self.States.push(new State(item));
        });
    }); 
}, 
error: function (exception) 
{ 
    alert( "fail" ); 
} 
});
```

My json object as string looks like this

```
{data:[{"id":"5345345","name":"dsfsdf","ssc":"","bic":"dgffdgfdg"},{"id":"123456","name":"SBI","ssc":"654321","bic":"vxvxc"}]}
```

js fiddle link is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/gz0s6413/2/)
What is my mistake ? Or do I need to do it by mapping plugin of knockout js?

Comment: What is the meaning of `self.PopulateStates` computed observable?

Comment: yes computed observable

Answer (score 0):

I use this knockout extension, declared before use.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.map = function (data, Constructor) {
    var mappedData = ko.utils.forEach(data, function () {
        return new Constructor(data);
    });

    this(mappedData);

    return this;
}
```

Then in my `$.ajax` request I do this:

```
success: function (data) 
{ 
    var jsondata = data['jsonObj'];
    self.PopulateStates = ko.observableArray().map(data, State);
});
```

You had the results in a `computed` observable which isn't what you need.

Another thing I have noticed is that your `jsondata` is set using the data that gets returned from the GET. You are asking that data for the field `jsonObj` however, looking at your JSON it seems you don't have this field. I think I am correct in saying you have `data` as the field with the list of items being returned.

If in your view model you have already declared `self.PopulateStates` which, I'm guessing you have. You can do this:

```
var State = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.property = ko.observable().set(data, "property");
}

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.PopulateStates = ko.observable();

    function getStates() {
        var request = $.ajax();

        request.done(function (data, msg) {
            if (data) self.PopulateStates.map(data, State);
        });
    }
}
```

If you notice in the `State` model I have  `self.property` using a custom `observable` function to set it. All this does is if there is data to set the property to, set it. Otherwise give it a default value. I also have a third parameter that I use when I want it to construct an object for me using the data. This is when I have say, a contact, with a `modifiedBy` property and this `modifiedBy` is a user object (or just a complex object)

***EDIT***

The main thing, which isn't an error, but isn't necessary is the `jQuery` inclusion. Knockout is built to work independant of `jQuery` so where you do `$(document).ready(function () {})` to make sure this loads on DOM ready isn't needed. This means you don't have to include `jQuery` if the page doesn't need it.

Here is the update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gz0s6413/3/), this will now work!

Comment: it doesn't work i am getting error undefine is not a function. i your ajax request where you ara passing parameters ?   function getStates() {
        var request = $.ajax();

        request.done(function (data, msg) {
            if (data) self.PopulateStates.map(data, State);
        });
    }

Comment: You need to use your `ajax` settings, I obviously haven't put any settings in because that is dependent on yours. if you create a fiddle with script in it. Then I can make modifications to show you how it works

Comment: just saw your other commenting, creating a fiddle now for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/gz0s6413/   its a link of fiddle i want to populate some data on load

Comment: i'm still getting error undefiened is not a function

Comment: does i need to include any other js for this ?? why it is pointing undefined  on this this line    var mappedData = ko.utils.forEach(data, function () {
        return new Constructor(data);
    });

Comment: Try it now, there were some javascript errors in there, plus I changed `forEach` to `arrayMap`, basically the same thing. If you want to use `forEach` the syntax is `arrayForEach`

Comment: self.States.map(data, State); in this instead of data jsondata has to come i think . and it still not working should i post my servlet logic

Comment: Yeah lets see that, also re read my post I have noticed something else about your code!

Comment: @user2142786 how have you got on?